# how to display list with elements horizontally

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I'm trying to display Groups horizontally with each group listing the members that belong to that group. For example:

```
   Group 1:           Group 2:       Group 3:
   1. Joe Blo         1. Bob         1. etc..
   2. Joe smith       2. Billybob
   3. Joe glow        3. Bobby
```

I'm not a fan of css, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
<ul id="grpId">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{                  
    <li>           
        Group @Html.DisplayName(item.GroupId.ToString())<br />
        <ol>
            @foreach (var student in item.GroupMembers)
            {
                <li>@String.Format("{0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName)</li>
            }
        </ol>

    </li>

}
</ul>
```

My CSS:

```
#grpId
{
    background-color:aliceblue;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

    #grpId li
    {
        height:300px;

        background-color: aliceblue;
        display: inline;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: large;
    }
        #grpId li ol
        {
            display: inline;
        }
```

Comment: Post the rendered html, not your server-side code. Also, show/describe what happens using your current code

Comment: You shouldn't need to see the rendered html if you understand razor

Comment: I don't, but I'm not the one asking for help...also the rendered html is more useful, because it allows us to make a simple mock-up for you without having to write the markup ourselves. If you make it easier for us to help you, you're more likely to get help.

Comment: I understand, good point. This is generated on the fly and is part of a partialview that is injected in a div so the rendered html isn't viewable unless there is another possible way maybe see it, I'm not too sure. Thx for your help below though, appreciate it. The -1 above is little harsh it's fine. :)

Comment: no problem. You can usually view the html by doing 'inspect element', whether with firebug or the chrome dev tools. Depends on your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following style:

```
#grpId
{
    overflow: auto;
}

#grpId > li
{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/6H37G/) 
Be sure to specify which type of `<li>` your css rule is targeting: `#grpId li` will affect both types of `<li>` elements, but `#grpId > li` specifically targets only those which are direct children of your `<ul>`

```
#grpId {
    background-color:aliceblue;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#grpId > li {
    height:300px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
}
ol > li {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: medium;
}
```